# Erro em Rota ao Acessar Site

Tags: php, laravel, framework

Quando adiciono essa rota no arquivo **routes.php**:

### routes.php

```
Route::get('postagem', function (){
   return "teste";
});

Route::get('/', function(){
    return View::make('hello');
});
```

Apresenta esse erro:

> Fatal error: Class 'Route' not found in C: \ wamp \ www \ laravel \ app \ routes.php on line 13

Uso Laravel 4.2, Wamp Server. Já fiz diversos comandos com o composer de atualizar, porém sem sucesso.

Comment: Digita na URL http://localhost/seusite/public/posting, o que que aparece ?

Comment: @TaoPaiPai  NOT Found 404

Comment: Como está sua URL ? Posta aí.

Comment: @TaoPaiPai  localhost/laravel/public/postagem

Comment: Então, mas o nome da sua rota é `posting` e não `postagem`.

Comment: @TaoPaiPai é postagem é porque coloquei essa pergunta no fórum em ingles dai eu só copiei

Comment: Só tem isso no seu arquivo de rota ? E o `.htaccess` ?

Comment: @TaoPaiPai esta assim 

>'<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>'

Comment: Quando você instalou o Laravel funcionou a página de teste ?

Comment: @TaoPaiPai sim, essa é a unica rota que funciona

Comment: Everson, poste o código do arquivo de rota inteiro na sua pergunta.

Comment: @TaoPaiPai pronto feito

Comment: Você instalou como o Laravel? E qual comando você usou pra criar o projeto? O problema aqui não parece ser com Apache e nem com permissão de pastas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta fazer assim:

Cria um Controller pelo comando:

`$ php artisan make:controller HomeController`.

Depois na rota apague tudo e faça:

`Route::controller('/', 'HomeController');`

Em **HomeController** coloque o código:

```
public function getIndex(){
    return "Teste";
}
```

Depois na URL digita:

> http://localhost/laravel/public/

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda foi top